# Sublime Text 3 - output panel (build system) ignores prints/stdout

Tags: python, sublimetext3, stdout, build-system

I have build system that outputs log of running application and its tests being run. What bothers me, is that sublime just ignores prints if I add them in code. If I use logging to output something, then it works, but using prints for quick checks is much more convenient.

Is there an option to enable stdout/prints in panel, so it would not be ignored?

If I would run same command through terminal directly, then I can see prints.

So if let say in my code is this:

`print "something..."`

It is just ignored and I do not see in output panel.

command and whole build system config looks like this:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python ~/openerp/scripts/odoo-run/run.py 10 -p 8079 --addons-path=~/odoo10/source/misc -d git_odoo -u project_task_sequence --test-enable",
    "name": "Odoo Run",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "/home/oerp/odoo10/odoo/",
    "syntax": "Packages/Makefile/Make Output.sublime-syntax",

}
```

In settings, the only thing I found that is related with output panel was this option: `show_panel_on_build`, which is enabled.

**Update**

Snippet of code to show what results I get:

```
def test_sequence_number_1(self):
    """Test how sequences were generated."""
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('Test')
    logger.warn('This is outputed')
    print "this is not outputed"
    ProjectTask = self.env['project.task']
    task_1 = ProjectTask.create({
            'name': 'Task 1 (test)',
            'project_id': self.project.id,
            'generate_seq_number': True,
        })
    ...
    ...
```

This is what I see in output panel through sublime:

```
...
...
2016-12-28 17:54:26,479 659 INFO git_odoo odoo.addons.project_task_sequence.tests.test_project_sequence: test_sequence_number_1 (odoo.addons.project_task_sequence.tests.test_project_sequence.TestProjectSequence)
2016-12-28 17:54:26,479 659 INFO git_odoo odoo.addons.project_task_sequence.tests.test_project_sequence: ` Test how sequences were generated.
2016-12-28 17:54:26,854 659 WARNING git_odoo Test: This is outputed
2016-12-28 17:54:27,271 659 INFO git_odoo odoo.addons.project_task_sequence.tests.test_project_sequence: test_sequence_number_2 (odoo.addons.project_task_sequence.tests.test_project_sequence.TestProjectSequence)
2016-12-28 17:54:27,271 659 INFO git_odoo odoo.addons.project_task_sequence.tests.test_project_sequence: ` Test sequence generation with custom task seq prefixes.
2016-12-28 17:54:27,616 659 INFO git_odoo odoo.addons.project_task_sequence.tests.test_project_sequence: Ran 2 tests in 1.137s
2016-12-28 17:54:27,616 659 INFO git_odoo odoo.addons.project_task_sequence.tests.test_project_sequence: OK
```

P.S. Though when I ran `nosetests -s` command through sublime build system, then prints were outputted properly. Don't know why this one is different.

Comment: Sublime captures stdout and displays it so this should work fine. Can you provide a small sample of code that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework, but the documentation suggests that `-s` tells nosetests not to capture stdout. So I would assume that this isn't a sublime issue and more that by default nosetests is eating stdout before Sublime gets to see it at all. http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#cmdoption-s

Comment: @OdatNurd you got it all wrong. It is the opposite. I said, it is working fine with nose, it is not working with my custom script that starts an application (see Build System Config). Though the script start an application just fine if I run it through terminal directly and I can see prints, but for some reason can't see through sublime panel.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said "Though when I ran nosetests -s command through sublime build system, then prints were outputted properly. Don't know why this one is different." I took that to mean that it worked the way you expected it to work (the prints were seen) when you used `nosetests -s`. Based on the documentation and your results, I assumed that `nosetests` captures stdout unless you tell it not to by passing `-s`.

Comment: Yes, its working with nosetests. Actually problem is not related with nosetests at all. I just gave it as an example, that in some cases stdout works, but in other cases it does not.